# In QGIS Web Client - How to click on a photo in an attribute table and load into a new browser tab?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

I have a map loaded into my QGIS web client, and have images loaded into my attribute table for a specific layer. Works great - when I click info on one of the layer attributes, it shows the image.

BUT - the image is very small. **I would like to be able to click the smaller version of the image and have it load the original image into a new browser tab.**

I am able to right click and click "open image in new tab" and it works, but I'd like anyone who looks at the map to be able to just click it and automatically have the image pop up in a new window.

Is this possible?